# Design patterns to share data in modern JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there any good design patterns to share data between class instances in modern, object-oriented JavaScript application?

For example, I'm building an app with components. They're class instances. Some of them are sharing same data. I know that you can use singleton services injected in the constructor. This solution is implemented in AngularJS framework. But is there any other solution without using singleton pattern? I'm looking for some articles about designing architecture for JavaScript application.

I created some kind of Injector which probably isn't the best solution:

```
export const Injector = {
  instances: {},

  add<T>(Class: { new(...args: any[]): T }, ...args) {
    const className = new Class().constructor.name;
    const instances = args.map((item) => this.get(item));
    if (!this.instances[className]) {
      this.instances[className] = new Class(...instances);
    }
  },

  get<T>(Class: { new(...args: any[]): T }): T {
    const className = new Class().constructor.name;
    return this.instances[className];
  }
};
```

Comment: I think the problem is, that people often confuse (or use interchangeably) DI and a DI-container. The most simplistic dependency injection used all over the place is this `(function(global, undefined){ /*someLibCode */ })(this);`. Imo. there's no good alternative to DI, but that doesn't always involve a DI-container

Comment: Your `Injector` *is* a singleton. Why are you using `class` syntax for it?

Comment: @Bergi Should I use an object? A Class syntax is clearer for me (if I can say that).

Comment: Yes, if you want to create an object, use an object literal. No need for `getInstance` fluff.

Answer (score 0):

In object-oriented programming, your program is objects that can communicate with other objects through their interfaces (invoke their methods).

For your needs, you can use a "regular" association with the object (put the object into the constructor).

```
class Greetings {
    hello() {
        return "Hello world!"
    }
}

class ForwardConsole {
    constructor(greetings) {
        this.greetings = greetings;
    }

    print() {
        console.log(this.greetings.hello());
    }
}

class BackwardConsole {
    constructor(greetings) {
        this.greetings = greetings;
    }

    print() {
        console.log(this.greetings.hello().split("").reverse().join(""));
    }
}

let greetings = new Greetings();
let fc = new ForwardConsole(greetings);
let bc = new BackwardConsole(greetings);
```

In the code, we have encapsulated (injected) the same object into different objects using a standard constructor.

Comment: It seems like in this case you'd also want the observer pattern. Your `Greetings` instance is stateless so sharing it doesn't really share data…

Comment: @Bergi you right, Greetings does not have a state, but its could be (I simplify the example). For example, Greetings could have a field x = “Hello world!” and the print() would return x, or Greetings could getting message from remote API, it is not so important. Important that object is not a data structure, object is entity that provide some service through methods and one object can use different objects (as I have shown through encapsulation, or for example just as a parameter of a method).

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that when the entity has a state to *share* with other components it should not only provide a getter but also implement an observable interface. It'll make the example more complex but also more useful.

Comment: @Bergi, if we want to use an object-oriented approach, we should avoid using getters. We have public methods and it's the concern of another entity to provide service in accordance with the contract. About getters and why it's an anti-pattern well stated by Martin Fowler - https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html.

Comment: I was referring to "*Greetings could have a field x = “Hello world!” and the print() would return x*", where `print` would be a getter. But yes, you should avoid the getters. Have the greeting provide the value to the consoles that are observing it.